# How to normalize a nested .json?

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

So I am using Mapbox web API and have a .json returned. I've been having trouble and difficulties parsing .jsons. One of the challenge I'm having is that the returned .json is nested. Here is the .json:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "query":[
      -73.989,
      40.733
   ],
   "features":[
      {
         "id":"locality.12696928000137850",
         "type":"Feature",
         "place_type":[
            "locality"
         ],
         "relevance":1,
         "properties":{
            "wikidata":"Q11299"
         },
         "text":"Manhattan",
         "place_name":"Manhattan, New York, United States",
         "bbox":[
            -74.047313153061,
            40.679573,
            -73.907,
            40.8820749648427
         ],
         "center":[
            -73.9597,
            40.7903
         ],
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -73.9597,
               40.7903
            ]
         },
         "context":[
            {
               "id":"place.2618194975964500",
               "wikidata":"Q60",
               "text":"New York"
            },
            {
               "id":"district.12113562209855570",
               "wikidata":"Q500416",
               "text":"New York County"
            },
            {
               "id":"region.17349986251855570",
               "wikidata":"Q1384",
               "short_code":"US-NY",
               "text":"New York"
            },
            {
               "id":"country.19678805456372290",
               "wikidata":"Q30",
               "short_code":"us",
               "text":"United States"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"region.17349986251855570",
         "type":"Feature",
         "place_type":[
            "region"
         ],
         "relevance":1,
         "properties":{
            "wikidata":"Q1384",
            "short_code":"US-NY"
         },
         "text":"New York",
         "place_name":"New York, United
States",
         "bbox":[
            -79.8578350999901,
            40.4771391062446,
            -71.7564918092633,
            45.0239286969073
         ],
         "center":[
            -75.4652471468304,
            42.751210955
         ],
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -75.4652471468304,
               42.751210955
            ]
         },
         "context":[
            {
               "id":"country.19678805456372290",
               "wikidata":"Q30",
               "short_code":"us",
               "text":"United States"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"country.19678805456372290",
         "type":"Feature",
         "place_type":[
            "country"
         ],
         "relevance":1,
         "properties":{
            "wikidata":"Q30",
            "short_code":"us"
         },
         "text":"United States",
         "place_name":"United States",
         "bbox":[
            -179.9,
            18.8163608007951,
            -66.8847646185949,
            71.4202919997506
         ],
         "center":[
            -97.9222112121185,
            39.3812661305678
         ],
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -97.9222112121185,
               39.3812661305678
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "attribution":"NOTICE: © 2021 Mapbox and its suppliers. All
rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service
(https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be
retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare."
}
```

I was able to load it into a dataframe using the following code snippet:

```
url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/-73.989,40.733.json?
types=country,region,locality&access_token=MY_KEY_HERE"

data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)

df = json_normalize(data, 'features')

return df
```

However, I see that I need to add [query] to it so I modified the relevant potion to look like:

```
url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/-73.989,40.733.json?
types=country,region,locality&access_token=MY_KEY_HERE"

data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)

df = json_normalize(data, 'features', ['query'])

return df
```

(The syntax I am following comes from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html))

The error I get states:

> **ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.**

The query field looks like this...

[image: Query field needs to be added to the dataframe]

I'm not sure what the error is stating and how to resolve it.

Here is my desired output dataframe:
[image: Desired Output]

I can do the cleaning and dropping of unneeded fields but I am having trouble getting the [query] field to appear.

Comment: Doesn't `requests.get().json` directly solves your problem?

Comment: What is your expected output? Specifically, what do you want to have in the DataFrame?

Comment: Hi Xitiz, using requests.get(url).json gives me an error: "You're trying to iterate through an object of type method, but objects of that type are not iterable." but trying out json_normalize works for me so I went with that.

Comment: Not_Speshal, here is the output I'm wanting. I inserted an image at the end of the table I would like. There's a lot of extra fields in the .json I don't need but I can drop those later. I'm having trouble getting that [query] field to be like my desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the column `query` after `json_normalize`:

```
df.insert(0, 'query', [data['query']] * len(df))
```

Comment: Corralien, I see the technique you're going for. I didn't think of appending it afterward. I did df = df.insert but it completely wiped everything and I left it as just df.insert and everything worked out great. Thank you very much! Problem solved! Out of curiosity, was there a way to squeeze in [query] during the json_normalize in one line? Or is it too much trouble and not worth investigating?